# ¿Cómo pasar imagen de ListView a un pictureBox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, listview, entity-framework-6, picturebox

Hola estoy queriendo pasar una imagen que se selecciona en un ListView a un PictureBox y no logro dar con la tecla.

Con este método lleno el ListView donde muestra una imagen miniatura y el id de la foto, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando seleccione una foto de esa lista me la muestre en grande en un pictureBox.

Lo que no se como hacer es capturar esa imagen debido a que no estoy guardando la ruta de la misma sino que, valga la redundancia, en el Listview la guardo como imagen

```
   private void MostrarImagenes()
    {
        var query = from fotos in db.fotos select fotos;
        if (query.Count() > 0)
        {  
            ImageList lista = new ImageList();
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                listView1.LargeImageList = lista;
                lista.Images.Add(item.idfoto.ToString(),Convertir_Bytes_Imagen(item.foto));
                var listViewItem = listView1.Items.Add(item.idfoto.ToString());
                listViewItem.ImageKey = item.idfoto.ToString();
            }

        }
        else { MessageBox.Show("no hay imagenes para mostrar"); }

    }
```

Comment: [mira esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520087/display-image-from-listview-to-picturebox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías almacenar las imágenes en un objeto `Dictionary` para poder recuperarlas a partir de la clave:

```
private Dictionary<string, Image> imagenes;

private void MostrarImagenes()
{
    var query = from fotos in db.fotos select fotos;
    imagenes = query.ToDictionary(i=> i.idfoto.ToString(), i=> Convertir_Bytes_Imagen(i.foto));
    if (imagenes.Count>0)
    {
        var lista = new ImageList();
        foreach (var item in imagenes)
        {
            listView1.LargeImageList = lista;
            lista.Images.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            var listViewItem = listView1.Items.Add(item.Key);
            listViewItem.ImageKey = item.Key;
        }

    }
    else { MessageBox.Show("no hay imagenes para mostrar"); }

}

private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0 || imagenes == null) return;

    pictureBox1.Image = imagenes[listView1.SelectedItems[0].ImageKey];
}
```