# Agregar un picturebox a una columna de un row especifico en un ListView control

Tags: c#, windows-forms, listview

Hola chicos tengo el siguiente `ListView`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este ListView tiene 3 columnas en la segunda colocó las URL mediante un botón que contiene este código:

```
    ListViewItem listViewItem= new ListViewItem();
    String url = textBox1.Text;
    listViewItem.SubItems.Add(url);
    listViewItem.Name = url;
    listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
```

y la tercera columna se deja vacía; una vez hidratado el `ListView` con las columnas URl y Status; he agregado un botón para validar estas URLS el cual tiene el siguiente código:

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        PictureBox picture = new PictureBox
        {
            SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
        };


        foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.Items)
        {

            if (webRequestManager.ValidateURL(eachItem.Name))
            {

                picture.Image = Properties.Resources.correct;

            }
            else
            {

                picture.Image = Properties.Resources.incorrect;

            }

            //Aqui no se que poner para que la columna status en el row especifico se Actualice y agregue el pitcute box.
        
        }

    }
```

***como podrán ver una vez que he generado el picture box no se como inyectarlo en la columna status de cada row.***

ya he buscado en el sitio y estos post sugeridos no logran o aportan a resolver mi escenario:

[Poscisionarse en columna y row especifico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/392609/46896)

[¿Cómo pasar imagen de ListView a un pictureBox?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/131531/46896)

***Este es mas o menos el resultado esperado:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Update***

He implementado un ImageList:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ImageList imagenes = new ImageList
            {
                ImageSize = new Size(16, 16),
                ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth8Bit
            };
            
            imagenes.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.correct);
            imagenes.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.incorrect);

            listView1.SmallImageList = imagenes;

            foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.Items)
            {

                if (webRequestManager.ValidateURL(eachItem.Name))
                {

                    listView1.Items[eachItem.Index].ImageIndex = 1;

                }
                else
                {

                    listView1.Items[eachItem.Index].ImageIndex = 0;

                }

            }

        }
```

Pero no he logrado hacer que la imagen aparezca en la columna #3 de status:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lograr poner una imagen en una columna debes hacer uso del **componente ImageList**. Como su nombre indica este control te guarda una colección de imágenes que podrán ser usadas en otros controles tales como el **ListView**.

Una vez que insertas el **control ImageList** vas a su **propiedad Images** y creas una colección de imágenes(insertas tantas imágenes como desees). Este **control ImageList** le da un índice a cada imagen de su colección de imágenes garantizando de esta forma un fácil acceso a cualquier imagen mediante el índice que le indiques(tal como ocurre con un arreglo).

Entonces para darle una imagen a cualquier columna del **ListView** harías:

```
listView1.Items[0].ImageIndex = 0;
```

Al primer registro del **ListView** le indicamos que ponga en la columna que deseas la primera imagen guardada en el **componente ImagaList**.

Revisa bien esto y adáptalo a tus necesidades.

***Update Adaptación Realizada:***

```
bool checkError = false;
ImageList imagenes = new ImageList
{
   ImageSize = new Size(16, 16),
   ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth8Bit
};
            
imagenes.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.correct);
imagenes.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.incorrect);
listView1.SmallImageList = imagenes;

foreach (ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.Items)
{
   if (webRequestManager.ValidateURL(eachItem.Name))
   {
      listView1.Items[eachItem.Index].ImageIndex = 0;
   }
   else
   {
      listView1.Items[eachItem.Index].ImageIndex = 1;
      checkError = true;
   }
}

if (checkError)
{
   MessageBox.Show("\nSe ha Detectado que una de las URL Ingresadas no es válida o no tiene conectividad!\n\n" + "La URL Incorrectas deben ser Removidas, luego Valida nuevamente para poder Guardar la Configuración!!!\n");
}
else
{
   button2.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: como se declara que es en la tercera columna que se debe insertar la imagen?

Comment: hice una prueba de lo que dices he investigue un poco; he agregado la actualización al post de que me esta fallando.

Comment: Pero es error de código o que no hace lo esperado?

Comment: no hace lo esperado ...  lo que haces inserta la imagen en la primera columna y quiero que aparezca en la tercera.

Comment: Ok dame un time

Comment: creo que no se puede en mi caso estoy creando subitems que son una extension de la primera columna... y no he encontrado la forma de inyectar la imagen como ultimo subitems

Comment: A ver @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent hay una forma de hacerlo y es ir al componente ListView y dar clic en la propiedad Columns y ahi reordenar las columnas a tu gusto

Comment: déjame probar a ver ...

Comment: ya lo probé y no me convence el resultado: https://i.imgur.com/0mVaIbj.png cuando se mueve la columna se lleva todo lo que hay dentro; incluyendo los checkbox ...

Comment: Me permites enriquecer tu respuesta con el código que he logrado con el cual doy por finalizado el desarrollo de este apartado??

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent si modifica lo que quieras